# Variance of Value Expressed as Number of Changing Bits

Tags: estimation, statistics

I consider values physical measurements, expressed as variables of type `int16`, `uint32`, `float` or other.
I consider a Gaussian model for measurements, i.e. I have estimates for the mean and standard deviation values.

The measurements are sent through a communication channel, which may introduce errors.
I wish to "flag" unlikely bits on statistical grounds, meaning if a significant bit changes, the decimal value could be multiple standard deviations from the mean.

The probability of measuring a decimal value which is `n` standard deviation from the mean is easily found using the complementary error function `erfc`, and is expressed as $$\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
1-\erf(n/\sqrt{2})
$$
For details look here: [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage).

My question regards the translation of this knowledge to the bit level. let us assume I have a decimal value that I deem unlikely, and I have a standard deviation $\sigma$:

1. How can I specify which bits are likely flipped?
2. How can specify which (lower) bits are statistically more prone to change value, and therefore I cannot make any statement regarding them?

Comment: Re: 1. Without noticing it, you're actually calling for *source coding* of your sampled Gaussian values. (Or equivalently, for non-uniform quantization, which would be even better). Once you make all possible values equally likely through that, any randomly chosen "wrong" number is more likely to be a likely value than an unlikely one, solving the problem.

Comment: Re: 2. Technologically, you'd always combine that source coding with appropriate channel coding, to minimize the influence of errors. And you can still make statements regarding them!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm aware source coding is a viable (and maybe better) solution. However, due to practicalities, this cannot always be used. Consider for instance GPS. It has standard messages, and moreover, you can't always control the tx side. If you're using some off-the-shelf device which sends its location in GPS coordinates you can only try to improve the reception.

Comment: **Especially** for GPS messages, you want source coding! As a matter of fact, if you consider what a Kalman filter does, it assumes Gaussian noise around a (hidden) true state (and a linear evolution of states), so if you, instead of sending a series raw GPS coordinates (or even worse: raw GPS NMEA messages or something) just send an initial observation, followed by Kalman filter updates, you can very drastically reduce data volume, up to a point where you have reduced your data volume enough to employ an 1/N-rate channel code for the same channel. That's both computationally cheap and clean.

Comment: I mean, look at GPS messages: most of their bytes *are redundant*; there's no need to transmit them. The parts of the message that do update, they update slowly or are noise, so very clearly a case for source coding. In this case, very simple source coding.

Comment: I agree. However, the point is you don't always control the transmitting side, nor do you always have a good model for data to employ a Kalman filter (which is heavily model dependent). I'm looking into ways of inferring redundancy from received data to improve the performance of the decoder without altering the transmitting side. What is described here is one approach. The model for data and noise considered here, can be thought of as an example model, or as a default model in the absence of a better one.